# Will std::system execute even after parent process has exited?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, c++11, system

I am running a **C++** console application in an **embedded linux** environment. I want to run a `std::system` command just like this. I have taken `tar` for an example.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::system("tar xvzf /path/to/some/file.tar.gz");
    exit 0;
}
```

**Question:**
If I exit the application right after the `tar` command like above, will the tar command continue to execute?
I understand that it depends a bit on how `tar` is implemented itself. But lets say `tar` doesn't work after parent process exits (*considering worst case scenario*), is there a way I can run the command `std::system` command safely in background and exit my app trusting that it will complete its job after my app or parent process has exited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands executed by `system()` will usually not continue after `system()` returns. `system()` starts a new process (using `fork() + exec*()` or `CreateProcess()` etc.) and then waits until that process is finished before it returns. If the command however spawns orphaned children, then they may live on.

This may have that effect depending on the `SHELL` used by `system()`:

```
std::system("nohup tar xvzf /path/to/some/file.tar.gz &");
```

Since `system()` starts the command using a shell (probably `/bin/sh`) and that it in turn uses the process's current environment (most notably `PATH` and variables that may be used to affect which shared libraries that are used by the command) - and that you can also send command strings with redirects, putting commands in the background (as shown above) etc. - it's often considered a security risk. One way to minimize the risk is to create your own system function that does not use a shell or the environment. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits> // std::common_type_t
#include <cstdlib>     // std::exit
#include <utility>     // std::forward

// fork, exec, waitpid
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template<typename... Ts>
int mysystem(Ts&&... ts) {
    int wstatus=-1;

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid==0) {          // in child process
        std::array<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, sizeof...(ts) + 1> cmd{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... };
        execv(cmd[0], const_cast<char* const*>( cmd.data() ));
        std::exit(1); // we'll only get here if execv failed starting the command

    } else if(pid!=-1) { // in parent process
        // wait for the child to terminate
        // the exit status from the child will be returned in wstatus
        waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0); // 0 = wait forever

    } // else { /* fork() failed */ }

    return wstatus;
}

int main() {
    //int ws = mysystem("/usr/bin/find", ".");
    //int ws = mysystem("/usr/bin/bash", "-i");
    int ws = mysystem("/usr/bin/tar", "xvzf", "/path/to/some/file.tar.gz");
    std::cout << "--------------------\n"
                 "Exit status:        " << WEXITSTATUS(ws) << "\n"
                 "Termination signal: " << WTERMSIG(ws) << "\n"
                 "Core dumped:        " << std::boolalpha << WCOREDUMP(ws) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::system` is a blocking call...
That means you don't reach the exit before the tar command itself is finished.